# NestJS and TypeORM - Problem with last update (glob Version 8.1.0)

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, glob

Since 4 days `typeorm` was updated to 0.3.12 and one important thing has changed: The **glob** package goes from `7.1.3` to `8.1.0` version. Here the package.lock.json:

```json
 "node_modules/typeorm": {
      "version": "0.3.12",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/typeorm/-/typeorm-0.3.12.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-sYSxBmCf1nJLLTcYtwqZ+lQIRtLPyUoO93rHTOKk9vJCyT4UfRtU7oRsJvfvKP3nnZTD1hzz2SEy2zwPEN6OyA==",
      "dependencies": {
        "@sqltools/formatter": "^1.2.5",
        "app-root-path": "^3.1.0",
        "buffer": "^6.0.3",
        "chalk": "^4.1.2",
        "cli-highlight": "^2.1.11",
        "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
        "debug": "^4.3.4",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "glob": "^8.1.0",
        "js-yaml": "^4.1.0",
        "mkdirp": "^2.1.3",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "sha.js": "^2.4.11",
        "tslib": "^2.5.0",
        "uuid": "^9.0.0",
        "xml2js": "^0.4.23",
        "yargs": "^17.6.2"
      },
```

The problem, I think, is that they have changed the follow:

> Only support node v12 and higher
> \ is now only used as an escape character, and never as a path separator in glob patterns, so that Windows users have a way to match against filenames containing literal glob pattern characters.
> Glob pattern paths must use forward-slashes as path separators, since \ is an escape character to match literal glob pattern characters.
> (8.0.2) cwd and root will always be automatically coerced to use / as path separators on Windows, as they cannot contain glob patterns anyway, and are often supplied by path.resolve() and other methods that will use \ path separators by default.

But read all about [here](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/blob/main/changelog.md).

So now if I do the follow in my NestJS app: (App.Module.ts)

```
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: process.env.DB_HOST, // '172.20.0.21',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'app',
      password: 'app',
      database: 'stop_causes',
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: true,
      namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
    }),
```

I got the follow error:

```
EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "MyEntity" was found....
.....
```

So, yes I can add the Entity itself to the entities array and it works. But I wanna hold the comfortable **glob** features. So how I use the new version of glob correctly?

#### What I have tried:

- Replace all **\\** to **/**
- Write the path per hand with **/**
- Relative path and full path

And nothing will work.

I use Windows for this. Any Idea?

Comment: Yes. It was fixed now. I think it will come in the next NestJS version. From the moment I use "autoLoadEntities" instead. Works as well!

Comment: Ah, I have overrided `typeorm` to 7.0 instead.